# Manejo de excepciones JAVA

Tags: java, excepciones

Estoy realizando un programa el cual recibe 2 numeros enteros por teclado y devuelve el resultado (division), el detalle es que quiero que si se produce una excepción (por ejemplo que se ingrese un flotante) que el programa no termine ahí, si no, poderle pedir nuevamente los numeros al usuario.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero1, numero2,resultado; 
        
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        try{
        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de a");
        numero1 = entrada.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de b");
        numero2 = entrada.nextInt();
        
        resultado = numero1 / numero2;
        
        System.out.println("El resultado es: "+resultado);
        
        
        }catch(InputMismatchException ex){
            System.out.println("Ingreso un numero no valido, solamente se aceptan enteros");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Así se comporta el programa en ejecución

```
run:
Ingrese el valor de a
5
Ingrese el valor de b
4.5
Ingreso un numero no valido, solamente se aceptan enteros
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una bandera que te indique cuando ya se han ingresado dos número correctos. Al igual, esta bandera te serviría para poder determinar que número es el que se ha ingresado con error.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Se inicializan porque al inicializarse en otro scope, el compilado marca error por usarlos fuera de la inicialización
        int numero1 = 0, numero2 = 0, resultado; 
        //Bandera para saber cuantos números correctos se han añadido
        int numerosCorrectos = 0;
    
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Si se han añadido 2 números correctos sale del ciclo while
        while(numerosCorrectos < 2) {
            try{
                // si aun no ha habido numero correctos, entonces se pide a de lo contrario se pide b
                if (numerosCorrectos == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de a; ");
                    numero1 = entrada.nextInt();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de b: ");
                    numero2 = entrada.nextInt();
                }
                //Si llega acá quiere decir que el número es correcto y se suma a la bandera
                numerosCorrectos++;
            } catch(InputMismatchException ex){
                // Se limpia el scanner.
                System.out.println("Ingreso un numero no valido, solamente se aceptan enteros");
                entrada.nextLine();
            }
        }
        resultado = numero1 / numero2;
    
        System.out.println("El resultado es: "+resultado);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :)